Scrapy won't download images in the *.MPO format - PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file
When Scrapy spiders tries to download an image that is in the .mpo format, it results in this error:
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7ff1297bbec0>

How do I make Scrapy/Pillow to process images with the .mpo extension?
Detailed error
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7ff1297801d0>
2024-05-09 10:26:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET URL> (referer: None)
2024-05-09 10:26:26 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (downloaded): Downloaded file from <GET URL> referred in <None>
2024-05-09 10:26:26 [scrapy.pipelines.files] ERROR: File (unknown-error): Error processing file from <GET URL> referred in <None>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1660, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = current_context.run(gen.send, result)
StopIteration: <200 URL>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py", line 493, in media_downloaded
    checksum = self.file_downloaded(response, request, info, item=item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scrapy/pipelines/media.py", line 153, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 119, in file_downloaded
    return self.image_downloaded(response, request, info, item=item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scrapy/pipelines/media.py", line 153, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 123, in image_downloaded
    for path, image, buf in self.get_images(response, request, info, item=item):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 139, in get_images
    orig_image = self._Image.open(BytesIO(response.body))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3339, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(msg)
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7ff1297bbec0>


Does it not do HEAD before PUT too?

@wRAR I am not sure. Another observation is that it looks like some images are not processed because of their file extension. Specifically, files with "*.mpo** - ERROR: File (unknown-error): Error processing file from <GET https://website.com/file.mpo> referred in <None>

If you are not sure then the claim in the title is not necessarily true. It's also not clear if that .mpo problem is the whole reason or not, you should clarify that in the post.

@wRAR I modified the question

"cannot identify file" sounds like it already tried using all the image formats it knows. File extensions are for humans after all. Edit your question with a stack trace and maybe the first hundred bytes of the file.

@Botje added the error output

If Pillow doesn't recognize this file you can't use ImagesPipeline, you could use FilesPipeline or a custom pipeline based on ImagesPipeline that skips these or skips handling for them.
